# Can't get indices with VBO working

Tags: c++, android, opengl-es2, vbo

I'm learning opengl for a few days only. Now I'm trying to use indices for my cube, but can't get it working, I don't see anything on screen.

```
struct Vertex
{
    GLfloat position[3];
    GLfloat color[4];
};
vector<Vertex> meshData = {
    {{-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.3f, 1.0f}},
    {{1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.3f, 1.0f}},
    {{1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.3f, 1.0f}},
    {{-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.3f, 1.0f}},
    {{-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.3f, 1.0f}},
    {{1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.3f, 1.0f}},
    {{1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.3f, 1.0f}},
    {{-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.3f, 1.0f}},
    {{-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f}, {0.0f, 0.5f, 0.3f, 1.0f}},
    };
vector<GLubyte> indices = {
    0, 4, 5, 0, 5, 1,
    1, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2,
    2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 3,
    3, 7, 4, 3, 4, 0,
    4, 7, 6, 4, 6, 5,
    3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2
};
```

loading:

```
// mesh
GLuint buffer[1];
glGenBuffers(1, buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, meshData.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &meshData[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
vboBufferId = buffer[0];

// indices
GLuint indicesBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &indicesBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(GLubyte), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
vboBufferId = indicesBuffer;
```

rendering:

```
glUseProgram(getShaderProgram());

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, getBufferId());
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, getIndicesBufferId());

glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle);
glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, position));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(colorHandle);
glVertexAttribPointer(colorHandle, 4, GL_FLOAT, false, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, color));

mvpMatrix = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * getModelMatrix();
glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, value_ptr(mvpMatrix));
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

P.S. I just noticed, that I'm getting warning `<qgl2DrvAPI_glDrawElementsInstancedXXX:893>: GL_INVALID_VALUE` in the logcat. What's wrong?

Comment: Look at the [documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml) for `glDrawElements` See if you think your values match up to the required parameters. For example, you might want to pass in your indices array.

Comment: `vboBufferId = indicesBuffer;` - is that really supposed to be `vboBufferId`? Not something like `indicesBufferId`?

Comment: I suggest you try with GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT instead of GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE - unsigned byte indices are unlikely to be supported in hardware.

Comment: @Byte56 I don't need to pass indices array through glDrawElements, because I have already passed it when loading.

Comment: @sftrabbit Yes, you are right, I need more attention. If you would write an answer, I would accept that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about debugging your code. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the buffer object name for your elements in `vboBufferId`, when I expect you are meaning to store it in some other variable like `indiciesBufferId`. Otherwise, you're just overwriting the name for the vertex buffer object that you previously stored there and losing it.